# Can be run on the command line, but not in a shell script?

Tags: shell, grep

I want to use `grep` to search for matching strings in the file, but because the file is too big, I only search for the first 500 lines.

I wrote in the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

patterns=(
llc_prefetcher_operat
to_prefetch
llc_prefetcher_cache_fill
)


search_file_path="mix1-bimodal-no-bop-lru-4core.txt"
echo ${#patterns[*]}
cmd="head -500 ${search_file_path} | grep -a "
for(( i=0;i<${#patterns[@]};i++)) do
cmd=$cmd" -e "\"${patterns[i]}\"
done;
echo $cmd
$cmd >junk.log
```

The result of running the script is:

```
3
head -500 mix1-bimodal-no-bop-lru-4core.txt | grep -a -e "llc_prefetcher_operat" -e "to_prefetch" -e "llc_prefetcher_cache_fill"
head: invalid option -a
Try'head --help' for more information.
```

On the penultimate line, I printed out the string of the executed command. I ran it directly on the command line and it was successful.
That is the following sentence.

```
 head -500 mix1-bimodal-no-bop-lru-4core.txt | grep -a -e "llc_prefetcher_operat" -e "to_prefetch" -e "llc_prefetcher_cache_fill"
```

Note that in the `grep` command, if I do not add the `-a` option, there will be a problem of `matching the binary file`.

Why does this problem occur? Thank you!

Comment: `head: invalid option -a` so head is seeing the -a, not grep - suggest perhaps the `|` needs to be escaped (just a guess)

Comment: Read [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Repeat until you're convinced that shell commands should __never__ be stored in strings.

Comment: (...if you're thinking about using `eval` to work around the problem, then read [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) in addition).

Comment: @John3136, adding more escaping doesn't fix the problem -- the problem is that the results of parameter expansions, command substitutions, etc. are only subject to string-splitting and glob expansion, but no other parsing steps, so a `|` created by one of those operations will _never_ be treated as syntax (unless one does something that restarts the parsing process from the beginning, but that way lie shell injection vulnerabilities)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - as I said, just a guess. Key part for me is that it was "head" not "grep" complaining about the -a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to build a string holding a complex command, you're better off using `grep`'s `-f` option and `bash` process substitution to pass the list of patterns to search for:

```
head -500 "$search_file_path" | grep -Faf <(printf "%s\n" "${patterns[@]}") > junk.log
```

It's shorter, simpler and less error prone.

(I added `-F` to the `grep` options because none of your example patterns have any regular expression metacharacters; so fixed string searching will likely be faster)

---

The biggest problem with what you're doing is the `|` is treated as just another argument to `head` when `$cmd` is word split. It's not treated as a pipeline delimiter like it is when a literal one is present.